# Find and Delete all Files, Directories, and changes made by an app

Tags: android, registry, user-profile

How do some apps know you've already installed their application?

They must be adding file to your phone that is archived even beyond the uninstall of the Application.

People have mentioned Device ID - which I have managed to change...

I know there is software (for windows) that lets you see all the changes on the registry after a software installation. 
Is there something similar for Android?